# Simple http/https redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redirect

Is there a lightweight web server that only does http/https redirects? Right now I am looking at using lighttpd, but even than seems like overkill for what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a single-function http daemon to do this? If so, the answer is most likely "No".

That said, every single major http daemon out there is able to do this.

If you know lighttpd, then use it. If not, give nginx a try.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something like what you describe, and I figured it was a long shot. Thanks.